# List having separate entries from different classes

Tags: c#, list, class, subclass

I have been working on a paint-type of program, and want to make the eraser erase the entire element if it is hit. I've been using an interface and subclasses like so:

```
public interface IPaint
{
   // some different methods
}

public abstract class StartAndEndTool : IPaint
{
   public List<IPaint> shapes = new List<IPaint>();

   // the methods again, this time abstract/virtual
}

public class RectangleTool : StartAndEndTool
{
   // overriding some of the methods
   // in one of the methods we edit the list, like follows:

   public override void Complete( ... )
   {
      // some mumbo-jumbo, and:

      shapes.Add(new RectangleTool());
   }
}

public class EllipseTool : StartAndEndTool
{
   // overriding some of the methods
   // in one of the methods we edit the list, like follows:

   public override void Complete( ... )
   {
      // some mumbo-jumbo, and:

      shapes.Add(new EllipseTool());
   }
}

public class EraserTool: StartAndEndTool
{
   // overriding some of the methods
   // in one of the methods we USE the list
}
```

Now when I use the `shapes` list in the `EraserTool` method, it says the list is empty. I have done some research but it seems the methods create sort of "separate lists". For example, when I draw a rectangle, then an ellipse, then a rectangle again, it will have a different amount of entries depending on which class it is being used in. So in this example: `shapes.Count` will be equal to 2 if written in the `RectangleTool` class, and will be equal to 1 if written in the `EllipseTool` class. I have tried using ICollections, but it does the same. How do I fix this?

Comment: Shapes is now a property of the tool, so it is only accessible inside the tool and every tool has its own list.

Comment: Or, well, accessible from anywhere since it is public, but still shapes should be defined somewhere where you define your tools and not as part of the tool.